# Not equal for linq operator in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two list i.e. csvlist and emplist
csvlist is a list (of CSV) and xml is a list(of xml)

I am trying to write a  linq query which updates the csv.attr if the csv.id is not equal to xml.id. However, in vb.net I don't know the operator for not equal.

In C# you can use != but what is the equivalent in vb.net>

```
public class CSV
   public property id as string
   public property attr as string
end class 

public class XML
   public property id as string
   public property attr as string
end class  

Dim csvlist as List(of CSV)
Dim xmllist as List(of XML)


Dim Query  = from csv in csvlist, xml in xmllist
                  where csv.id != xml.id
                  select xml
```

Id is an alphanumeric field

Comment: `csv.id <> xml.id` or `Not(csv.id = xml.id)`.. The first search result for `vb not equal` wil lgive you the answer.

Comment: Basically `!=` in c# equal `<>` in VB.Net.

Comment: i added <> but i get duplicated results  . how can i get distinct results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Not operator.

```
Dim query  = From csv In csvlist, xml In xmllist
             Where Not csv.id = xml.id
             Select xml
```

As for your Distinct part"

No duplicates in csv:

```
Dim query  = From str In csv.Distinct, xml In xmlList Where csv.id <> xml.id
```

No duplicates from the result set.

```
Dim query  = (From str In csv.Distinct, xml In xmlList Where csv.id <> xml.id).Distinct
```

Comment: i get duplicates when i use `select csv` and a correct correct set  when i use select xml`but the set is repeated three time

Comment: did you try `Distinct` in the query?